# Qual a função da opção -m do Python?

Tags: python

Para descobrir a versão do Django que tenho instalado, uso o seguinte comando no terminal:

```
python -m django --version
```

Qual a função da opção `-m` deste comando?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você pode sempre executar

```
python --help
```

para obter a descrição detalhada do comando e dos parâmetros. Veja a saída:

```
usage: python [option] ... [-c cmd | -m mod | file | -] [arg] ...
Options and arguments (and corresponding environment variables):
-b     : issue warnings about str(bytes_instance), str(bytearray_instance)
         and comparing bytes/bytearray with str. (-bb: issue errors)
-B     : don't write .py[co] files on import; also PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=x
-c cmd : program passed in as string (terminates option list)
-d     : debug output from parser; also PYTHONDEBUG=x
-E     : ignore PYTHON* environment variables (such as PYTHONPATH)
-h     : print this help message and exit (also --help)
-i     : inspect interactively after running script; forces a prompt even
         if stdin does not appear to be a terminal; also PYTHONINSPECT=x
-I     : isolate Python from the user's environment (implies -E and -s)


-m mod : run library module as a script (terminates option list)


-O     : optimize generated bytecode slightly; also PYTHONOPTIMIZE=x
-OO    : remove doc-strings in addition to the -O optimizations
-q     : don't print version and copyright messages on interactive startup
-s     : don't add user site directory to sys.path; also PYTHONNOUSERSITE
-S     : don't imply 'import site' on initialization
-u     : unbuffered binary stdout and stderr, stdin always buffered;
         also PYTHONUNBUFFERED=x
         see man page for details on internal buffering relating to '-u'
-v     : verbose (trace import statements); also PYTHONVERBOSE=x
         can be supplied multiple times to increase verbosity
-V     : print the Python version number and exit (also --version)
         when given twice, print more information about the build
-W arg : warning control; arg is action:message:category:module:lineno
         also PYTHONWARNINGS=arg
-x     : skip first line of source, allowing use of non-Unix forms of #!cmd
-X opt : set implementation-specific option
file   : program read from script file
-      : program read from stdin (default; interactive mode if a tty)
arg ...: arguments passed to program in sys.argv[1:]
```

Verificando o parâmetro `-m mod`, há dito que tal parâmetro executa um módulo Python como um *script*. Neste caso, seria o mesmo que `django --version`.

Answer (score -4):

Porque a forma como o python localiza módulos na hora de importar pode gerar resultados inesperados.

crie essa estrutura de arquivos e pastas

```
.
├── a
│   ├── a.py
│   └── __init__.py
└── b.py
```

```
# b.py
var = 11
```

```
# a.py
import sys
print(sys.vars[0])

from b import var
print(f'{var=}')
```

se você executar `$ python -m a.a` python irá inserir o diretório atual em `sys.path` e executará normalmente gerando na shell o resultado esperado

```
'pasta/onde/esta/esse/script'
var=11
```

mas se você executar `$ python a/a.py` você verá que python insere em `sys.path` apenas o diretório que contém o módulo executado e, por isso, python não reconhece o módulo `b` que está sendo importado e você receberá o seguinte resultado

```
'pasta/onde/esta/esse/script/a'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pasta/onde/esta/esse/script/a/a.py", line 4, in <module>
    from b import var
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'b'
```

leia o racional sobre como executar módulos com scripts no [PEP 338](https://peps.python.org/pep-0338/)

Comment: Sugestão, no inicio da resposta explique o significado da opção -m e após a explicação levante a pergunta *"Mas por que é preciso usar essa opção?"* e então siga com o texto que já publicou.