# Qual a diferença entre pacote e módulo em Python?

Tags: python

Existe diferença entre um pacote e um módulo em Python? Se existe diferença, é possível dar exemplos de pacotes e módulos?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## Módulo

Na [documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html) diz:

> *A module is a file containing Python definitions and statements. The file name is the module name with the suffix .py appended.*

Isto é, um arquivo `foo.py` é considerado um módulo Python se possuir definições e instruções da linguagem. Ou seja, qualquer arquivo Python pode ser considerado um módulo. Para este caso, o nome do módulo seria `foo`, definido pelo nome do arquivo, sem a extensão.

Por exemplo:

```
# foo.py

def foonction ():
    print("Função no módulo foo")
```

Em qualquer outro arquivo Python, você poderá importar o módulo e utilizar suas definições:

```
# main.py

import foo

if __name__ == "__main__":
    foo.foonction() # Função no módulo foo
```

No [glossário](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-module) há:

> *An object that serves as an organizational unit of Python code. Modules have a namespace containing arbitrary Python objects. Modules are loaded into Python by the process of importing.*

Isto é, módulo é um objeto (em Python tudo é objeto) que serve como uma unidade organizacional de código Python. Módulos têm um *namespace* contendo objetos Python arbitrários (instâncias, classes, funções, etc.).

## Pacote

Na [documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages) diz:

> *Packages are a way of structuring Python’s module namespace by using “dotted module names”.*

Isto é, o pacote é a forma de definir *namespaces* para os módulos, permitindo que inúmeros módulos de mesmo nome coexistam sem interferência. Basicamente, um pacote Python é um diretório que contém módulos:

```
sopt/
  __init__.py
  foo.py
```

Para utilizar um módulo de um pacote, basta importá-lo utilizando os nomes pontilhados:

```
# main.py

import sopt.foo

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sopt.foo.foonction() # Função no módulo foo
```

A diferença entre um diretório comum para um pacote Python é justamente a presença do aquivo `__init__.py`. Sem ele, o diretório não será considerado um pacote e os módulos ficarão inacessíveis.

No [glossário](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-package) há:

> *A Python module which can contain submodules or recursively, subpackages. Technically, a package is a Python module with an `__path__` attribute.*

Isto é, o pacote é um módulo que contém sub-módulos ou, recursivamente, sub-pacotes. Tecnicamente, um pacote é um módulo Python que possui o atributo `__path__`.

Por isso que mesmo que a documentação cita alguma funcionalidade para módulos, é permitido usá-la sobre pacotes também, pois o pacote é um módulo. Por exemplo, utilizando o parâmetro `-m mod` no comando `python`:

```
python -m django --version
```

como discutido [nesta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/207330/5878) outra pergunta.

Comment: Nas versões mais recenetes, o arquivo `__init__.py`  é opcional.