# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'autorizacoes'

Tags: python, diretório, import

Como posso importar uma pasta utilizando Python no Spyder ?

Atualmente tenho a seguinte estrutura de dir

```
Gestao
|
|_ Aplicacao
    |
    |_ Autorizacoes
```

No script

```
import pandas as pd
import imaplib
import email
import autorizacoes
```

Consigo importar todas as bibliotecas menos "autorizacoes". Utilizando o Visual Code não retorna o erro que estou recebendo agora.

```
import autorizacoes

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'autorizacoes'
```

Quando se utiliza o Spyder a forma de importar uma pasta é diferente, existe alguma outra forma?

Comment: Em python, para que um diretorio seja um modulo vc precisa acrescentar um arquivo como o nome `__init__.py`.

Comment: Sim, dentro da pasta "autorizacoes" eu já tenho um arquivo chamado "__init__.py"

Comment: Mas não basta ser `init.py` tem que ser `__init__.py`, ou seja tem que começar e terminar com 2 "underlines".

Comment: Além disso, o python é *case-sensitive*, ou seja você tem que usar o `A` maiúsculo assim como colocou no nome da pasta

Comment: Fiz isso também e continua dando o mesmo erro

Comment: Tentou a minha resposta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veja se funciona assim:

1) Crie a estrutura inicial (os comandos abaixos são para linux)

```
$ mkdir -p gestao/aplicacao/autorizacoes
```

2) Crie os arquivos `__init__.py`

```
$ touch gestao/__init__.py
$ touch gestao/autorizacoes/__init__.py
```

3) Na pasta autorizacoes crie e edite um arquivo com o nome `hello.py` e adicione o seguinte conteúdo:

```
def hellow():
    return 'Hello World!'
```

4) Na pasta raiz (gestao), crie o arquivo `sayhello.py` com o seguinte conteudo:

```
from aplicacao.autorizacoes.hello import hellow
```

Com o comando `tree` vc pode ver a estrtura:

```
$ tree
.
├── aplicacao
│   ├── autorizacoes
│   │   ├── hello.py
│   │   └── __init__.py
│   └── __init__.py
└── sayhello.py
```

5) Execute `sayhello.py` na linha de comando:

```
$ python sayhello.py
```

A saida deverá ser:

```
Hello World!
```

> Editada
>   Revendo o codigo na sua questão, não fica claro se Autorizacoes é um pacote ou um módulo, se vc tem duvidas a respeito de que seja um pacote e/ou um módulo, [veja essa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/207339/7412) aqui no STOpt. No codigo de exemplo da sua pergunta, vc faz: `import autorizacoes`, mas se autorizacoes for uma pacote (um pacote pode ser resumido como um diretorio que contem modulos), vc deveria fazer: `import autorizacoes.nome_do_modulo`

Comment: ainda nada, só consegui importar a pasta utilizando "os.chdir ('caminho da pasta')"

Comment: Fez o teste que eu propus? Exatamente igual? Veja que no seu codigo da pergunta vc faz um `import  autorizacoes` mas se vc estiver na "raiz", vc tem que importar da forma como faço no meu exemplo, com o caminho inteiro, que seria `import aplicacao.autorizacoes`

Comment: Ou se quizesse importar explicitamente as funcoes em um arquivo: `from aplicacao.autorizacoes.nome_modulo import funcao1, funcao2 ...`